# Mathematica: selecting elements from a list based on criteria

Tags: list, select, wolfram-mathematica, criteria

Mathematica question here.

I'm looking to extract elements from a list that meet a certain criterion: namely, that the sum of the first and second elements is greater than or equal to 70. Here's what I've tried:

```
points = Table[{racing, sport, 8*racing + 12*sport}, {racing, 0, 40}, {sport, 0, 60}]
selected = Select[points, points[[All, All, 1]] + points[[All, All, 2]] >= 70 &]
```

I get an empty list back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Several different misunderstandings involved. First, & sort of only makes sense when used with #. Second, your table of lists of three items has two iteration variables and so is not just a long list of items {r,s,8r+12s} for various values of r and s that I think you are expecting. Use smaller numbers and count your layers of {}. Next, Point[[All,All,1]] probably isn't doing what you think it is. Again try with smaller numbers and see. By this point I'm mostly guessing what you really wanted. Try this Select[Flatten[points,1], #[[1]]+#[[2]]>=70&] and see if that is what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what your trying to achieve?

```
points = Flatten[Table[{racing, sport, 8*racing + 12*sport},
    {racing, 0, 40}, {sport, 0, 60}], 1];
selected = Select[points, #[[1]] + #[[2]] >= 70 &]
```